# Move files depending on occurence in a python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

do you know  if it is possible if you have a folder filled by fasta files such as :

```
seq1.fa
seq2.fa
seq3.fa
seq4.fa
seq5.fa
seq6.fa
seq7.fa
...
seq1000.fa
```

and to only keep, or move into a new folder, the sequences which are present in a dataframe such as:

```
seq_names
seq1
seq3
seq8
seq89
```

And that with python exclusively?

the new folder would be then:

```
seq1.fa
seq3.fa
seq8.fa
seq89.fa
```

Thank you for you help :)

Comment: - Find the contents of the current working directory using `os` library - Check if each one exists in the dataframe using `for` and `in` statements. - Do the move operation using `os` library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- scan the directory using `os.listdir()`
- match file radix against a `set` (extracted from dataframe or whatever) for fast lookup
- move/remove if match

like this:

```
import os,shutil

matches = {"seq1","seq3","seq8","seq89"}
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if os.path.splitext(filename)[0] in matches:
       # move
       shutil.move(os.path.join(filename,directory),new_directory)
       # or just copy:
       # shutil.copy(os.path.join(filename,directory),new_directory)
```

to just delete the other files:

```
    if not os.path.splitext(filename)[0] in matches:
       # remove
       os.remove(os.path.join(filename,directory),new_directory)
```

Comment: perfect thank you :)

Comment: btw and if I just want to copy and paste them into a new directory? And as you can see, the file name is not totaly matching with the seq_names because of the .fa

Comment: `os.path.splitext(filename)[0]` contains the filename without the .fa extension. you mean move them AND remove the extension?

Comment: okok, no I mean I want to copy all files in the liste and paste them into a new one but without removing anything into the first file

Comment: in that case replace `shutil.move(os.path.join(filename,directory),new_directory)` by `shutil.copy(os.path.join(filename,directory),new_directory)`  (same args)